# Android memory leak when use a timerTask in custom view

Tags: android, memory-leaks, timer

I use a timer task in my Custom view,the custom view is used in activity, so the custom view reference a context of Activity,The custom view main method look like this:

```
public RushBuyCountDownTimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_countdowntimer, this);
    tv_day_decade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_day_decade);
    tv_day_unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_day_unit);
}   
public void start() {

    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        clockTimeTask = new ClockTimeTask();
        timer.schedule(clockTimeTask, 0, 1000);
    }
}

class ClockTimeTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
public void stop() {
    setVisibility(View.GONE);
    context = null;
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
    if (clockTimeTask != null) {
        clockTimeTask.cancel();
        clockTimeTask = null;
    }
}
```

And in my activity,i call the method stop() in onStop():

```
 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopFlashClock();
    }
}
public void stopFlashClock() {
    if (holder != null) {
        holder.rbcvFalshPromoteTime.stop();
    }
}
```

The rbcvFalshPromoteTime is my custom view.but the activity leaked,the following picture is result that i find in Android monitor.

[Reference tree in andorid monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twjB9.png)

How can i fix this? I can't use a static class,if i can use WeakReference,how to code it?

Comment: I suspect that there is a third variable, or static variable, holding on to your custom View or to your Activity. Just the Activity holding the View, and the View holding the Activity, I believe, would not prevent garbage collection in modern systems. Every View in Android references it's context.

Comment: @lionscribe Thank you for reply to me! i use Leakcanary to help me find the leak,it show that  [Leakcanary result](https://jp.pinterest.com/pin/270216046372826740/), may be it caused by the timer in my custom view.

Comment: Why can't you use a static class?

Comment: @TedHopp Because if i use a static class,the some view fields in my custom view will be changed to static, Android Studio tell me "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)".